# Friendliness and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose i have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
protected:
    virtual ~A() { cout << "A destructor reached." << endl;}

    friend class Z; 
};

class B : public A
{
protected:
    virtual ~B() { cout << "B destructor reached." << endl; }
};

class Z
{
public:
    void Test();

    friend class A;
};

void Z::Test()
{
    A* derived = (A*) new B();

    delete derived;
}

int main()
{
    Z test;
    test.Test();
}
```

What is going to happen, will the B destructor be called? Is it legal? And if it's not, is there any way to call the derived constructor without making every class derived from A friend of Z?

Comment: @Beta yes i could, but i wanted to be sure that the behaviour is not somewhat related to my compiler (VS 2012) and stardard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Standard, §11.5/1 "access to virtual functions," says

> The access rules (Clause 11) for a virtual function are determined by its declaration and are not affected by the rules for a function that later overrides it.

So you can call `B::~B` as long as you have access to `A::~A`. But you must call it through `A` because `Z` does not have access to `B`.

By the way, the friend declaration in `Z` is useless since nothing is private or protected in it.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two questions involved here.

Yes, B's destructor will be called. That's how polymorphism works, that's how virtual destructors work, it's by design and it's a good thing.

The fact that a member function that is protected (or even private) in B but virtual and available (e.g. public) in A can be invoked via A* may seem a little odd at first, but it's by design too. What's the alternative? The only other option I can see would be to forbid inheritance that increases the restriction of a virtual member function; what good purpose would that serve?

If you don't want a method to be accessible, don't derive it from an accessible virtual parent method.